# Draw empty rows

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

How to draw rows in cxGrid even if there is no data to display?

Like this

[image: Like This one]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check this thread on DevExpress website:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q421788

Comment: thanks, I have already seen this
I did not succeed in make it work on Delphi